# How to replace text in PDF documents?

Tags: pdf

When I am modifying a PDF document, there is a situation that the same name or number needs to be modified to the same content. If there is a replacement function, it is much more convenient than to find and modify one by one. Both Word and Excel have this function, so does PDF also have this function?

Comment: You can open read and edit PDF files using LibreOffice Writer and LibreOffice Draw.

Comment: What are you using to modify your PDF document?

Answer (score 2):

No, it hasn't, in principle. PDF is not a format that is intended to be edited. It is a format that represents a final version for print or screen display. Open the source file, do the edits, then export the updated version to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

### Find & Replace Text in PDF Documents

You can open read and edit PDF files using LibreOffice Writer and LibreOffice Draw.

LibreOffice Writer has a **find and replace option** that works for me.

Formatting is not always the same as an Adobe Acrobat PDF.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about **TEXT BASED PDF**
then my answer is **YES**, you can edit it using Libre office draw and export directly as pdf....